# Send consol.log content to a php page

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap table with content.
Using the consol.log I am able to collect the needed values from the selected rows.
I am getting the Magento-id of the selected rows in consol.log
On button click, I would like to open an URL passing the values of console.log using POST  (for example page.php). is there a way to achieve that?

```js
    var $table = $('#table');
    var $button = $('#button');
    function getRowSelections() {
      return $.map($table.bootstrapTable('getSelections'), function(row) {
        return row;
      })
    }

    $('#button').click(function() {
      var selectedRows = getRowSelections();
      var selectedItems = '\n';
      $.each(selectedRows, function(index, value) {
        selectedItems += value.magento_id + '\n';
      });

      console.log(selectedItems);
    });
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.5/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.5/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<div id="toolbar">
  <button id="button" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Show Selected Rows</button>
</div>
    <table id="table" data-toolbar="#toolbar" data-toggle="table" data-maintain-meta-data="true">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
          <th data-field="id">Item ID</th>
          <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Product Name</th>
          <th data-field="magento-id" data-sortable="true">Magento id</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Chair</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Sofa</td>
          <td>$500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>Desk</td>
          <td>$300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Rug</td>
          <td>$200</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing your data to the console you can assign it to a string variable. Then you can extend your HTML with another form which contains a hidden field - and set the value of that field to the content of your string variable. You should also add an empty IFRAME with some name/id and then set the `target` attribute of the new form to this IFRAME to avoid a page reload when submitting the auxiliary form. After all that you can POST the form.